# Listen to all touch events in an iOS app

Tags: objective-c, ios, events, touch

Is it possible to somehow listen to, and catch, all the touch events occurring in an app?

The app I'm currently developing will be used in showrooms and information kiosks and I would therefore like to revert to the start section of the app if no touches has been received for a given couple of minutes. A sort of screensaver functionality, if you will. I'm planning to implement this by having a timer running in the background, which should be reset and restarted every time a touch event occurs somewhere in the app. But how can I listen to the touch events? Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need a subclass of `UIApplication` (let's call it `MyApplication`).

You modify your `main.m` to use it:

```
return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"MyApplication", @"MyApplicationDelegate");
```

And you override the method `[MyApplication sendEvent:]`:

```
- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent*)event {
    //handle the event (you will probably just reset a timer)

    [super sendEvent:event];
}
```

Comment: The down size of this is that we cannot do this at runtime. Any other workarounds?

Comment: how to figure which even it was ?

Comment: @AsadullahAli See `UIEvent` documentation (https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIEvent_Class/index.html). Every event has a type, a subtype and also a set of touches you can inspect.

Comment: Let suppose it was a UIButton Tap.. Can I figure it out here ?

Comment: i have some 50 viewControllers and I want to capture all button taps I can't find anything helpful in the documentation :/

Comment: @AsadullahAli No and you are doing it the wrong way. Ask a separate question.

Comment: @Sulthan thanks Anyways I have done it with help of your code

Comment: Can you please review my code here and suggest if it's recommended https://github.com/aliasad106/sendEvent-for-All-touches/blob/master/MyApplication.m

Comment: @Sulthan What is the Swift 2 equivalent? There is no `main.m` file in Swift. Could you post a clear step by step Swift answer if possible please?

Answer (score 7):

A subclass of `UIWindow` could be used to do this, by overriding `hitTest:`. Then in the XIB of your main window, there is an object usually simply called `Window`. Click that, then on the right in the Utilities pane go to the Identities (Alt-Command-3). In the *Class* text field, enter the name of your `UIWindow` subclass.

**MyWindow.h**

```
@interface MyWindow : UIWindow
@end
```

**MyWindow.m**

```
@implementation MyWindow

- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UIView *res;

    res = [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];

    // Setup/reset your timer or whatever your want to do.
    // This method will be called for every touch down,
    // but not for subsequent events like swiping/dragging.
    // Still, might be good enough if you want to measure
    // in minutes.

    return res;
}   

@end
```

Comment: The problem here is that you do not get any information when touches end.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a tap gesture recognizer for this. Subclass `UITapGestureRecognizer` and import `<UIKit/UIGestureRecognizerSubclass.h>`. This defines `touchesBegan:`, `touchesMoved:`, `touchesEnded:` and `touchesCancelled:`. Put your touch-handling code in the appropriate methods.

Instantiate the gesture recognizer in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` and add it to `UIWindow`. Set `cancelsTouchesInView` to `NO` and it'll pass all touches through transparently.

Credit: [this post](http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/monitoring-all-ios-touches/).

Comment: Web archive link: http://web.archive.org/web/20171017053303/http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/monitoring-all-ios-touches/

Answer (score 3):

Create a Class "VApplication" that extends from UIApplication
 and paste these code to corresponding class

> VApplication.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

// # of minutes before application times out
#define kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes 10

// Notification that gets sent when the timeout occurs
#define kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification @"ApplicationDidTimeout"

/**
 * This is a subclass of UIApplication with the sendEvent: method 
 * overridden in order to catch all touch events.
 */

@interface VApplication : UIApplication
{
    NSTimer *_idleTimer;
}

/**
 * Resets the idle timer to its initial state. This method gets called
 * every time there is a touch on the screen.  It should also be called
 * when the user correctly enters their pin to access the application.
 */
- (void)resetIdleTimer;

@end
```

> VApplication.m

```
#import "VApplication.h"
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@implementation VApplication

- (void)sendEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    [super sendEvent:event];
    // Fire up the timer upon first event
    if(!_idleTimer) {
        [self resetIdleTimer];
    }

    // Check to see if there was a touch event
    NSSet *allTouches       = [event allTouches];

    if  ([allTouches count] > 0)
        {
        UITouchPhase phase  = ((UITouch *)[allTouches anyObject]).phase;
        if  (phase == UITouchPhaseBegan)
            {
            [self resetIdleTimer];         
            }
        }
}

- (void)resetIdleTimer 
{
    if  (_idleTimer)
        {
        [_idleTimer invalidate];
        }

    // Schedule a timer to fire in kApplicationTimeoutInMinutes * 60


//  int timeout =   [AppDelegate getInstance].m_iInactivityTime;
    int timeout =   3;
    _idleTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeout
                                                  target:self 
                                                selector:@selector(idleTimerExceeded) 
                                                userInfo:nil 
                                                 repeats:NO];

}

- (void)idleTimerExceeded
{
    /* Post a notification so anyone who subscribes to it can be notified when
     * the application times out */


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
     postNotificationName:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];
}


@end
```

Replace the Class name "VApplication" to our

> Main.m

file like this

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, @"VApplication", NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));

    }
}
```

Register a notification for your corresponding view controller

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidTimeout:) name:kApplicationDidTimeoutNotification object:nil];
```

And once the timeout occur the notification will fire and handle the event like this

```
- (void) applicationDidTimeout:(NSNotification *) notif //inactivity lead to any progress
{


}
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to use this since UITapGestureRecognizer was not catching all touch events for me.

Answer (score 1):

You could put a transparent view at the top of the view hierarchy, and choose in that view whether to handle the touch events it receives or pass them through to lower views.

Comment: That'll only work for an app that shows only one view. It breaks for example as soon as you present another view controller.

Comment: Well, a `presentModalViewController:animated:` would obscure your view or am I missing something? Or are you suggesting to have the transparent view inserted into every view controller? That certainly would be a lot of work and fragile as you must always make sure to not accidentally put a view above it. Or is there an easy way to ensure this?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 4.2
1. Create subclass of UIApplication object and print user action:

```
    import UIKit
    class ANUIApplication: UIApplication {

        override func sendAction(_ action: Selector, to target: Any?, from sender: Any?, for event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
            print("FILE= \(NSStringFromSelector(action)) METHOD=\(String(describing: target!)) SENDER=\(String(describing: sender))")
            return super.sendAction(action, to: target, from: sender, for: event)
        }   
    }
```

2. In AppDelegate.swift file you will find application entry point @UIApplicationMain Comment that and Add new swift file **main.swift**
   and add following code to main.swift file

> import UIKit
>
> UIApplicationMain(
>       CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
>       NSStringFromClass(ANUIApplication.self), NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self))

ANUIApplication is class where we added action logs.
AppDelegate is default app delegate where we wrote application delegate methods.(Helpful for tracking action and file name in big project)