# Detecting touch activity in ios app

Tags: ios

I need to store actual NSDate value in AppDelegate when I recognize that user used app.

But how to define that user uses app?
I tried `-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` on my base UIViewController but this only detecting touches on non-clickable areas, so I don't capture it when user clicks button (or any clickable component actually).

By using app I mean pretty much any interaction with an app, like touching the screen when the app is active.

What would be the way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this from the AppDelegate. Whenever the app is launched, it will call `applicationDidBecomeActive:` And with this, you will get be able to tell the user launched the app, or brought it back up.

You can then log this however you want and use it however you want

**UPDATE**

If you specifically are looking to detect every time someone touches inside of your app, you may want to just make sure that every button click, table scroll, etc calls back to a logging class and does whatever you need. And you can still have that `touchesBegan` method to get all other touches

Comment: how this helps me in logging user activity inside opened app?

Comment: You asked how to define that the user used the app. That will let you know they at least opened the app. Also don't downvote my answer when it was submitted before you fixed the question

Comment: The way I interpreted that was you put that because that is what you tried. Simple misunderstanding.

Comment: your UPDATE is very poor solution, you know that? It would require a lot of coding, not very efficent. Check my answer if you want to know how to do that efficiently

Comment: One other solution would be to have some semi-transparent view over everything, but the short answer is there really is no easy way to get a blanket option of touch anywhere on the screen especially when you have buttons and scroll views everywhere

Comment: Thats even worse idea, because it would interupt communicating with other views laying below. Again, check my answer :)

Comment: Well fantastic, glad you could have figured it out by doing a little research

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right here:

[Listen to all touch events in an iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8444184/listen-to-all-touch-events-in-an-ios-app)

I overwriten UIWindow class and captured every touch in app using `- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event`